# Introductory text on voting theory

Tags: reference-request, voting-theory

Some years ago I read about a [famous theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrow%27s_impossibility_theorem) by K. Arrow on rank-order voting systems. My interest in voting theory topic has been spurred by the use of MeekSTV in our moderator elections.

As such, I'd like to know if there is some nice, introductory text on voting theory where I could learn more about this subject.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an elementary text: [Mathematics and Politics: Strategy, Voting, Power, and Proof](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387776435).

Comment: Thanks, this looks interesting.

Comment: @A.P. Probably, the book I referenced is way too elementary. If you'd like to see some math, [these notes](http://xaravve.trentu.ca/pivato/Teaching/voting.pdf) might be of interest.

Comment: Sadly I didn't have time to properly look at the book, yet. Those notes seem quite interesting, too, and I would definitely like to see some math. Thank you (again).